# Why is a value not getting copied to the clipboard in javascript?

Tags: javascript, clipboard

I'm using Google App Engine Go SDK and I want to put some basic javascript code into my HTML templates that will use parameters passed from the application. The template looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function CopyToClipboard()
    {
        CopiedTxt = document.selection.createRange();
        CopiedTxt.execCommand("Copy");
    }
</script>
[...]
<form name="Form1">
    <input type="hidden" name="link" value="{{.Link}}">
    <input type="button" onClick="CopyToClipboard()" value="Copy to clipboard" />
</form>
```

What the code is supposed to do is copy the `{{.Link}}` value into the clipboard. But instead of getting things like `http://example.com` in the clipboard, I get `{{.Link}}`, even though the page source of the executed template clearly reads

```
<input type="hidden" name="link" value="http://example.com">
```

How can I make the javascript work properly with the GAE Golang template?

Comment: From what you said, you couldn't possibly get `{{.Link}}` in your clipboard unless the text `{{.Link}}` is actually in the source of the page. Are you sure you didn't already have `{{.Link}}` in your clipboard and the javascript simply didn't do anything?

Comment: @KevinBallard Hmm, I guess you are right, I should be more careful next time...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do with app engine, templates, or go. The problem is that `.execCommand()` will not generally work. Clipboard access is not something that can be done successfully through javascript. You must use a [flash plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript).